# Need to submit editable data to backend on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have to serialize my data and send it to the backend through ajax. I tried doing it using method told in datatable but it doesn't work for me.

I have a table which is editable. Few fields are editable and those editable data should be submitted to the backend in the serial they are entered. I tried below solution but its not working for me:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Handle form submission event
$('#subcpskam').on('click', function (e) {
    // Prevent actual form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize form data
    var data = table.$('input,select,textarea').serialize();

    // Submit form data via Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submitAccount.htm',
        data: data,
        console.log(data);
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Server response', data);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to submit datatable's full data on submit button click but I can see data in the console but can't submit it to the database.

[image]

Comment: Do not use ` console.log(data);` in the middle of your ajax options. Delete that line or put it before your ajax call

Comment: which language are you using for save data to database?
please check your URL extension.

Comment: when am using var data = $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize(); am getting full data of table but to send it to backend i need to separate it row wise but if am using var rowData = table.rows( ).data(); getting values row wise but input fields are not picked up. So now i want a solution where I can segregate data from serialize, rowwise. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: we r using spring and db is db2

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it, I hope it will be work.

```
// var data = table.$('input,select,textarea').serialize();

var data = $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();
```

[Here Reference Link](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)